# Find the limit of the function below

Tags: limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I was solving the limit at zero of this function :

$f(x) = x(\frac{1}{x} -\large\lfloor{(\frac{1}{x})}\rfloor)$

See this image>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCcKM.jpg)

I thought of the corollary of the sandwich theorem (which we use a lot in class)

As $x \to 0$

$(\frac{1}{x} -\large\lfloor{(\frac{1}{x})}\rfloor)$
and  is bounded between 0 and 1

Then the function should tend to zero

Is my method correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe thank you